Handle duplicates in SQL output
Working on a dataset containing users watching content from multiple genres. I want to come up with combination of genres (group of 2 genres) and count of users watching content from both genres.
On self joining and getting the data below is the output I'm getting

Ideally I want one row for each combination. How to remove the additional row from my output?
select genre1, genre2, count(uid) as User_count 
from (
  select a.uid, a.content_genre as genre1, b.content_genre as genre2 
  from (
      select content_genre, uid 
      from table 
      group by 1, 2
  ) a
  left join ( 
    select content_genre, uid 
    from table 
    group by 1, 2
  ) b on a.uid=b.uid and a.content_genre <> b.content_genre
)
group by 1,2 
order by user_count desc



Please edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output in text format instead of an image, This will make it easier for us to help you.

I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear? Also, as @SelVazi mentioned, please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Try a.content_genre < b.content_genre instead of a.content_genre <> b.content_genre.

So you want to get the results in which there's no repetition of group-1 and group-2 genres. In the image you shared you don't want the rows 1 and 3.
Try this query:-
select genre1, genre2, count(uid) as User_count  from (   select a.uid, 
         case when a.content_genre < b.content_genre then a.content_genre else b.content_genre end as genre1,
         case when a.content_genre < b.content_genre then b.content_genre else a.content_genre end as genre2   from (
      select content_genre, uid 
      from table 
      group by content_genre, uid   ) a   join ( 
    select content_genre, uid 
    from table 
    group by content_genre, uid   ) b on a.uid = b.uid and a.content_genre <> b.content_genre ) group by genre1, genre2 order by User_count desc;


My full example

CREATE TABLE `vote_analytics_new`.`users_genres` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `user_id` INT NOT NULL , `genre_id` INT NOT NULL , `date` DATETIME on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE `users_genres` CHANGE `date` `date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '4');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '5');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1');

INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '2', '4');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '2', '5');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '3', '2');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '3', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '3', '2');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '3', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1');


INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '4', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '4', '1');
INSERT INTO `users_genres` (`id`, `user_id`, `genre_id`) VALUES (NULL, '4', '1');

sql to debug:
select 
count(1) as total,
genre_id
from users_genres group by genre_id

final sql:
select g1.total + g2.total as final_total, g1.genre_id as g1_genre_id, g2.genre_id as g2_genre_id from (
    select 
    count(DISTINCT(user_id)) as total,
    genre_id
    from users_genres group by genre_id
) as g1

LEFT join (
    select 
    count(DISTINCT(user_id)) as total,
    genre_id
    from users_genres group by genre_id
) as g2 on g1.genre_id < g2.genre_id

where g2.genre_id is not null

it will be great to have a cache_genre_total table
where you will store sum for each genre
this will help a lot your server response
